# Objects as default values in c++

Tags: c++

is there a way to have a default Object for parameters in C++ functions? I tried

```
void func(SomeClass param = new SomeClass(4));
```

and it worked. However how would I am I supposed to know wheter I have to free the allocated memory in the end? I would like to do the same without pointers, just an Object on the stack. is that possible?

Comment: I don't see any explicit pointer here

Comment: to avoid pointers, memory allocation and so on, you can use this: `void func(SomeClass param = SomeClass(4));`. Your function will receive SomeClass object by value and will destroy it automatically after the function call

Comment: Does SomeClass have an implicit constructor from SomeClass* ?

Comment: how does it worked ? `new SomeClass(4)` returning a pointer to SomeClass while the function expect an instance. but without the `new` there is no problem. +1 since I never thought of trying this before.

Comment: This code generally does not work. A full working example would have been better.

Comment: @CashCow or worse, a `SomeClass( void * )` There's a train-wreck waiting to happen.

Comment: Guys thank you ;) I habe a lot to learn, I know :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it but you don't need the `new` keyword.

```
void func(SomeClass param = SomeClass(4));
```

This method has the advantage over using `new` in that it will be automatically deleted at the end of a call so no memory management is needed.

An alternative is to use shared pointers.

Answer (score 7):

```
void func(SomeClass param = new SomeClass(4));
```

This can't work because new returns a pointer

```
void func(SomeClass param = SomeClass(4));
```

should work and the object doesn't need to be freed.

Comment: It can work if `SomeClass` has a constructor that takes `SomeClass*`. I admit that is unlikely, and I use the word "work" very loosely.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Nice addition, a bit scary.

Answer (score -2):

You could use overloading:

```
void func(const SomeClass&) const;
void func() const {
  SomeClass* param = new SomeClass(4);
  func(param);
  delete param;
}
```

Comment: At least use pointers and delete afterwards, if you want this approach

Comment: `SomeClass param = new SomeClass(4);` does not work as `new` returns a pointer.